# Screen blinks randomly since installing ubuntu 22.04 LTS (using Nvidia-Driver-510 by default)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, screen, 22.04

My screen blinks randomly since I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (fresh install), previously I used Elementary OS and had no problems with my screen or my graphics card.
I'm using Nvidia Driver 510 by default.
My questions are :

1. Has anyone experienced something similar?
2. How to find out the problem?
3. How to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ask ubuntu. As this is probably a GPU driver issue, it might be helpful to also provide the model of the GPU. I have not seen something similar using the same driver on Kubuntu (though Kubuntu runs on x11 and not wayland). Do you have the same problem when running an x11 session?

Comment: Hi, thanks in advance for responding to my question. Here is a description of my GPU driver: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930M] / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2). And I use X11 by default.

Answer (score -1):

have same issue after switching to wayland.
only today this switch became available.
graphics nvidia tu104 geforce rtx 2060.
nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-510 (proprietary, tested).
everything ok on x11

Comment: Hello and welcome to ask ubuntu too...Can you give directions on how to activate the switch please?

Comment: on login screen select user. then a gear appears in bottom right corner with 2 options: ubuntu and ubuntu on wayland